# What is the meaning of 'instituted estate'?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, phrase-meaning

> Marriage was a divinely **instituted estate** that God intended for
>   everyone who desired it, and only very few, they thought, could remain
>   single and abstain from sexual relations.

Source: Martin Luther: A Very Short Introduction - Scott H. Hendrix

Meaning of 'estate' here is 'dignity' or 'legacy' or 'heritage'?

I didn't understand at all what is the purpose of 'instituted' here.

Comment: @WeatherVane That could be an answer.

Comment: @WeatherVane Please do as an answer so that I can approve it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an archaic use of **estate**, please see [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/estate)

> **4** *archaic, literary*
>   A particular state, period, or condition in life.
>   *The holy estate of matrimony*

The second question is overlooking the inclusion of **divinely** as part of the phrase

> **divinely instituted**

which means

> sanctioned by a deity, or holy.